# Generate a column for each file matching a glob

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm having difficulties with something that sounds relatively simple. I have a few data files with single values in them as shown below:

data1.txt:

```
100
```

data2.txt

```
200
```

data3.txt

```
300
```

I have another file called header.txt and its a template file that contains the header as shown below:

```
Data_1    Data2   Data3
-         -       -
```

I'm trying to add the data from the data*.txt files to the last line of Master.txt

The desired output would be something like this:

```
Data_1    Data2   Data3
-         -       -
100       200     300
```

I'm actively working this so I'm not sure where to begin. This doesn't need to be implemented in pure shell -- use of standard UNIX tools such as awk or sed is entirely reasonable.

Comment: I think you need another file or pattern on how to connect `Data_1` header to `data1.txt` file or do you just assume some alphabetical order? Why don't you just `cat header.txt; cat data*.txt | tr '\n' ' '` ?

Comment: Tags should be for tools the question is actually *about*, not tools you merely speculate that someone might use in writing an answer. If you're good with all standard UNIX tools, the unix tag covers it.

Comment: With bash: `cat header.txt <(cat data1.txt data2.txt | tr '\n' ' ') data3.txt | column -t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste` is the key tool:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec >>Master.txt
cat header.txt
paste $'-d\n' data1.txt data2.txt data3.txt |
while read line1
do
    read line2
    read line3
    printf '%-10s %-10s %-10s\n' "$line1" "$line2" "$line3"
done
```

Comment: This looks really good also, but it doesn't append the Master.txt file

Comment: Now it does: Simple redirect appended.

Comment: Instead of having `>> Master.txt` at two different points at the file, you might just put `exec >>Master.txt` once at the top. That's also a little more efficient at runtime, since it's only opening the output file a single time.

Comment: @user7649922, I'll note that the simplicity has some tradeoffs -- this assumes *exactly three* files. Is that given in the question as something known to be true? I assumed you'd need one column per `data*.txt` file, and thus to have code that could adjust itself / be correct if the number of files changed.

Comment: that's correct. I've actually simplified the problem, there are dozens of the data.txt files which will have unique names. The names of these files will not change. The next challenge I have is somehow placing the data from those text files to be aligned with the header names. This is in the event I have to change the header (e.g I insert a new/unique header name). I'll have to write a new question for this.

Comment: Change the format part of `printf` to follow your wanted format. With the current `"%-10s "` the text is printed left adjusted with 10 chars (or more, if the text is larger) +  1 space as separator.

Comment: I'm in a little bit of a pickle.... I have to use "tcsh" rather than "bash" and it seems the script above won't run.... i get "exec: Too few arguments" any ideas??

Comment: Then remove the line and change 2 lines to `cat header.txt >>Master.txt` and `done >>Master.txt` .

Answer (score 1):

As a native-bash implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0+ needed" >&2; exit 1;; esac

declare -A keys=( )       # define an associative array (a string->string map)
for f in data*.txt; do    # iterate over data*.txt files
  name=${f%.txt}          # for each, remove the ".txt" extension to get our name...
  keys[${name^}]=$(<"$f") # capitalize the first letter, and read the file to get the value
done

{                                       # start a group so we can redirect output just once
  printf '%s\t' "${!keys[@]}"; echo     # first line: keys in our associative array
  printf '%s\t' "${keys[@]//*/-}"; echo # second line: convert values to dashes
  printf '%s\t' "${keys[@]}"; echo      # third line: print the values unmodified
} >>Master.txt                          # all the above with output redirected to Master.txt
```

---

Most of the magic here is performed by [parameter expansions](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

- `${f%.txt}` trims the `.txt` extension from the end of `$f`
- `${name^}` capitalizes the first letter of `$name`
- `"${keys[@]}"` expands to all values in the array named `keys`
- `"${keys[@]//*/-}` replaces `*` (everything) in each key with the fixed string `-`.
- `"${!keys[@]}"` expands to the *names* of entries in the associative array `keys`.

Comment: This looks like its working, however, Its adding Data1 Data2 Data3 (with the dashes underneath). The headers are already in the Master.txt

Comment: I don't think you specified that the headers were already there in the question; I read it ask asking how to create them.

Comment: Also, thank you so much for all the details! this is really helpful

Comment: ...that said, the first two of the three `printf` lines write the header and then the line of dashes, so you can just take them out if you don't want that functionality.